# Drop label in Prometheus, but keep it for alertmanager

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

Is there a way to configure Prometheus to drop (don't save to database) certain label, but keep and pass it to alertmanager when alert arises?

This label is only matters in the moment when alert is active. I don't want to store it's history.

E.g. `my_instance_id` should be kept for alertmanager to use it in alerts text, but should not be saved into the Prometheus database:

```
up{instance="myhostname", job="myjob", my_instance_id="12345"}
```

I know it is possible to add/modify labels for alertmanager  only with `alert_relabel_configs`, but if I drop certain label in Prometheus (to avoid saving it in database) with `metric_relabel_configs` - it would be no such label for `alert_relabel_configs` to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

Alert rules are evaluated on the stored data, not freshly scrapped ones. And thus can only use labels that are present in storage.